# How to pass values from the parent application to an application that is loaded inside an iFrame in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a parent application that contains the iframe. I have another application in angular Js that is loaded inside this iframe. now I want to pass some values from parent website to the application that is loaded inside the iframe.

Comment: anything could be in the iframe, the only way would be to pass the data to your server and have some mechanism for whatever is in the iframe to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a directive with an isolate scope.

```
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).directive('iframe', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              some: '='
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              console.log(scope.some);
          }
      };
    }
);
</script>


<div ng-app="myApp">
    <iframe some="'thing'" src="wat.html"/>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/azn2f/)

Then you can with it as you wish inside the iframe. Here I pass a string, but of course you can pass scope variables from the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

few possibilities but one is to create a global value

```
var iframe = $("iframe#idOfYourIframe").first();
iframe.contentWindow.value = scope.value;
```

then in application running inside iframe you can access it as global object

```
$window.value
```